# git rebase messes up file with "No newline at end of file"

Tags: git, newline, cvs, rebase

I have the following set-up for my Git repositories:

- "Central" bare repository
- 2 cloned repositorys
- file "test.txt" in the repository

The file looks like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

It has no newline (\n, \n\r, \r) at the end. The last character is "5".

Now I modify the file in my first cloned repository like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
```

I commit this change and push it to my central repository. Again this file has no newline at the end.

In my second repository I do not pull. But I change the file like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 4
Line 5
```

Line 3 was deleted. This file has no newline at the end either. Now I commit this change. Afterwards I pull with `--rebase` and the file in the rebased commit looks this way:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 4
Line 5Line6
```

I know that a text file should end with a newline by standard. But is there a way to avoid this behavior?

My system set-up is this:

- OS: Windows 10
- Git: 2.11.0.windows.1
- Git-UI: Git Extensions 2.49
- KDiff3: 0.9.97 (32-bit)

Research done:

- The behavior does not occur when there is a newline at the end of the file.
- If a changed file contains a newline there is a conflict shown at least. But the automatic merge is not good.

Reasons for doing this:

I am migrating from CVS and would like to keep a straight forward commit history by now. This is why I would like to use rebasing. But the migrated repository contains some text files without newlines at the end of the files. A workaround would be to add newlines in all text files in the repository. But I would like to avoid massive changes.

Comment: This doesn't help, but perhaps it provides some explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/600360.

Comment: Is there any way you can do a one-time add of newlines to all files associated with your cvs-->git migration?